# How do I merge two Git branches, with specific commit ids, into one branch?

Tags: git, merge, commit, git-branch, git-checkout

I have two commits:

```
[branch]: [commit_id]
justin: 94943b74ba273a9f4009
jzbranch: 6070aada7b8a690d410b
```

How do I merge the two branches, into jzbranch, and resolve any differences between the two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do I merge two Git branches, with specific commit ids, into one
>   branch?

```
git checkout jzbranch

git merge [commit_id] jzbranch
```

or

```
git merge [commit_id] 6070aada7b8a690d410b
```

because git allows to merge several branches/commits to one.

Then run `git mergetool` or simple `git status` (in second case you only will see conflict files and then you would open these files with any editor you like). I prefer second way.

After that mandatory make new commit

Answer (score 1):

1. Checkout the jzbranch branch
   `git checkout jzbranch`
2. Merge in justin
   `git merge justin`
3. If there are any conflicts, run `git mergetool` after git mergetool runs, use `git commit` to commit the final merge.

Answer (score 1):

```
git branch newbranch 6070aada7b8a690d410b
git checkout newbranch
git merge 94943b74ba273a9f4009
```